# Jquery DataTables: failed to pass variable based on class to MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, .net-4.0

My DataTables version is 1.10.15. Jquery 1.9.1, Jquery UI 1.9.2.

I specify `"order": [[3, 'desc']]` but when server receive it, it's always 0 and null.

Same for `value` and `regex` of `Search`, null.

Pagination and page size are working though. I can go to other page and change page size.

It seems like server only receive:

```
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
```

Server cannot receive:

```
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public Search search { get; set; }
    public List<Order> order { get; set; }
```

What went wrong?

I created test project using .Net 4.5 and it's working, but why not in .Net 4?

[Reference](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#tableRolesUsers').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: '@Url.Action("List", "RolesUsers", new { Area = "Administration" })',
                type: 'POST',
                failure: function (result) {
                    alert(result.sEcho);
                }
            },
            "language": {
                "search": "",
                "searchPlaceholder": "Search..."
            },
            "order": [[3, 'desc']],
            "columns": [
                 {
                     "className": 'details-control',
                     "sorting": false,
                     "orderable": false,
                     "data": null,
                     "defaultContent": ''
                 },
                 { "data": "component", title: "Role" },
                 { "data": "user", title: "User" },
                 { "data": "auth_value", title: "Auth. Value" },
                 { "data": "create_by", title: "Create By" },
                 { "data": "create_on", title: "Create On" },
                 { "data": "modified_by", title: "Modified By" },
                 { "data": "modified_on", title: "Modified On" }
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 2]
        });
    });
</script>

public class ViewModelRoleUser
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public Search search { get; set; }
    public List<Order> order { get; set; }
    public List<T_Auth_User_Master> roleUserList;
}

public class Column
{
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool searchable { get; set; }
    public bool orderable { get; set; }
    public Search search { get; set; }
}

public class Search
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string regex { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int column { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}

public class RolesUsersController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult List(ViewModelRoleUser viewModelRoleUser)
    {
        // action inside a standard controller
        int filteredResultsCount;
        int totalResultsCount;
        var res = BLL.RoleUserHandler.SearchRolesUsers(viewModelRoleUser, out filteredResultsCount, out totalResultsCount);

        var result = new List<T_Auth_User_Master>(res.Count);
        foreach (var s in res)
        {
            // simple remapping adding extra info to found dataset
            result.Add(new T_Auth_User_Master
            {
                auth_value = s.auth_value,
                component = s.component,
                create_by = s.create_by,
                create_on = s.create_on,
                modified_by = s.modified_by,
                modified_on = s.modified_on,
                user = s.user
            });
        };

        JsonResult jsonResult = Json(new
        {
            // this is what datatables wants sending back
            draw = viewModelRoleUser.draw,
            recordsTotal = totalResultsCount,
            recordsFiltered = filteredResultsCount,
            data = result
        });
        return jsonResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `DataTable` has problem for handling collection or reference type properties passed from JSON object. Using simple `int` properties are fine because they're associated to JS' `Number` type.

Comment: @pop Please can you try updating "proccessing": true to "processing":true. There is spelling mistake. Reference link:-https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html

Comment: @J-Mean thanks but with the spelling mistake rectified, the result is still the same.

Comment: @Pop This demo will help you https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-datatables-plugin-server-side-integration/